# Unity Prefab Script Variables are the same values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a prefab that is instantiated at runtime and basically tracks the time that it is alive since being instantiated, the problem is is that with all of the prefabs that I create the variable time_alive is the same across all instances.

I've added the code that I've used to create the prefab as well as the definition of the prefab. What would I need to do/what am I missing?
[image]

Comment: I have a feeling it has to do with sendmessage, i only get this behavior when I call a function within these controllers using sendmessage

Comment: Ive switched how this code works to not be using sendmessage and it now works

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: In none of the code you posted there is anything called `time_alive` ...

Answer (score 0):

Ive fixed this by not using sendmessage